# Country code finding script in python

Tags: python, json, request

Python script to convert an ip-address to it's country code.
The information is fetched from the website 'https://freegeoip.net/json/'.

**Is there any better way other than this?**

```
import  json
import  requests
import subprocess

# clearing the screen.
subprocess.call('clear',shell=True)
msg = 'country code finder'

# Making the header.
print('')
print(' ',msg.upper())
print(' ','-' * len(msg))
print('')

lookup_ip = input(' Enter Your Ip Address : ')

# Fetching the country code from 'https://freegeoip.net/json/'
# The reply will be in json  format.
try:

    lookup_string = 'https://freegeoip.net/json/'+lookup_ip
    reply = requests.get(lookup_string)
    geodata= json.loads(reply.text)
    print('')
    print(' Country Is ::' , geodata['country_code'])
    print('')

except:
   print(' Unable to Fetch', lookup_string)
   print('')
```

Comment: Is there a question about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is.

```
import requests


ip = input('Enter Your Ip Address: ')
try:
    response = requests.get('https://freegeoip.net/json/{0}'.format(ip))
    response.raise_for_status()
    json = response.json()
    print('Country is {0}'.format(json.get('country_code', 'unknown')))
except:
    print('Unable to fetch')
```